# Stratified k-fold Cross Validation in R

Tags: r, data-mining, cross-validation, sampling, multiclass-classification

Suppose I have a multiclass dataset (iris for example). I want to perform a stratified 10 fold CV to test model performance. I found a function in the package `splitstackchange` called `stratified` that gives me a stratified fold based on the proportion of the data I want. So if I want a testing fold it would be 0.1 of the data rows.

```
#One Fold
library(splitstackchange)
stratified(iris,c("Species"),0.1)
```

I want to know how to implement this function or any other form of stratified cv in a 10-fold loop. I couldn't crack the logic behind it. Here I include a reproducible example.

```
    library(splitstackshape)
    data=iris
    names(data)[ncol(data)]=c("Y")
    nFolds=10

    for (i in 1:nFolds){
      testing=stratified(data,c("Y"),0.1,keep.rownames=TRUE)
      rn=testing$rn
      testing=testing[,-"rn"]
      row.names(testing)=rn
      trainingRows=setdiff(1:nrow(data),as.numeric(row.names(testing)))
      training=data[trainingRows,]
      names(training)[ncol(training)]="Y"
    }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at `caret`? It can do this sort of thing quite easily.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. thnks

Answer (score 1):

Use **caret** package for n-fold cv. I would suggest [this](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) very informative link on caret.

You many found the below solution useful.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

data=iris

## split data into train and test using stratified sampling
d <- rownames_to_column(data, var = "id") %>% mutate_at(vars(id), as.integer)
training <- d %>% stratified(., group = "Species", size = 0.90)
dim(training)

## proportion check
prop.table(table(training$Species)) 

testing <- d[-training$id, ]
dim(testing)
prop.table(table(testing$Species)) 


## Modelling

set.seed(123)

tControl <- trainControl(
  method = "cv", #cross validation
  number = 10, #10 folds
  search = "random" #auto hyperparameter selection
)


trRf <- train(
  Species ~ ., #formulae
  data = training[,-1], #data without id field
  method = "rf", # random forest model
  trControl = tControl # train control from previous step.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's late but i hope i can help someone.
The sample code helps me:

```
library(splitstackshape)


dat1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:100,
              A = sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"), 100, replace = TRUE),
              B = rnorm(100), C = abs(round(rnorm(100), digits=1)),
              D = sample(c("CA", "NY", "TX"), 100, replace = TRUE),
              E = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE))



flds=list()
dat=dat1

for(i in 1:10){
  j=10-(i-1)
  if(j>1){
  a=stratified(dat, c("E", "D"), size = 1/j)
  flds[[i]]=a$ID
  dat=dat%>%filter(ID %in% setdiff(dat$ID,a$ID))
  } else{
  flds[[i]]=dat$ID  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I ended up using lists as you did in my final code way in the past and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`caret` package is a good choice.

`createFolds(y, k = 10, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)` will return the indexes of test fold `y` for 10-fold CV.

`createMultiFolds(y, k = 10, times = 5)` will return the indexes of test fold `y` for 5 times 10-fold CV.

The data are stratified according to the label `y`.

Learn more: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/11/caretcreatefolds-vs-createmultifolds/