# Having trouble with model validation. Is this the next step after selecting a model?

Tags: r, statistics, model-validation

I've run negative binomial hurdle models and chose one based off of AIC and BIC.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to validate my model. K-fold test doesn't work because the classifications (more than 2) are not balanced. I can't figure out how to do stratified K-folds in R (lots of code for Python online). I've looked into creating stratified folds using caret but I'm not advanced enough to understand what to do afterwards. I also tried looking into likelihood ratio test and it seems to be way beyond my level.

I'd really appreciate any help figuring out how to finish the whole modeling process.

Comment: is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262807/stratified-k-fold-cross-validation-in-r

Comment: This post is off-topic in SO. I Suggested moving to Cross Validated

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. I saw this before but the coding was beyond my comprehension. I took a closer look today and will look into caret some more.

Comment: @GuedesBF I can't seem to figure out how to move the post?